# Problems with preserving object references in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, datacontractserializer

I'm trying to ensure that my object references are preserved when serialized over WCF, but the `CreateSerializer` on my overriden `DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior` is never called. Can anybody help me out with this.

This is my code:

**Custom DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior:**

```
public class ObjectGraphDataContractSerializerBehavior : DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ObjectGraphDataContractSerializerBehavior"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="operationDescription">The operation description.</param>
    public ObjectGraphDataContractSerializerBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription)
        : base(operationDescription)
    {

    }

    public override XmlObjectSerializer CreateSerializer(Type type, string name, string ns, IList<Type> knownTypes)
    {
        return new DataContractSerializer(type, name, ns, knownTypes,
            int.MaxValue /*maxItemsInObjectGraph*/,
            false/*ignoreExtensionDataObject*/,
            true/*preserveObjectReferences*/,
            null/*dataContractSurrogate*/);
    }

    public override XmlObjectSerializer CreateSerializer(Type type, XmlDictionaryString name, XmlDictionaryString ns, IList<Type> knownTypes)
    {
        return new DataContractSerializer(type, name, ns, knownTypes,
            int.MaxValue /*maxItemsInObjectGraph*/,
            false/*ignoreExtensionDataObject*/,
            true/*preserveObjectReferences*/,
            null/*dataContractSurrogate*/);
    }


    public static void SetDataContractSerializerBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription)
    {
        foreach (OperationDescription operation in contractDescription.Operations)
        {
            operation.Behaviors.Add(new ObjectGraphDataContractSerializerBehavior(operation));
        }
    }
}
```

**Starting service host:**

```
    var serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof (Service));
    serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof (IService), new NetTcpBinding(), DummyUrl);
    foreach (var endpoint in serviceHost.Description.Endpoints)
        ObjectGraphDataContractSerializerBehavior.SetDataContractSerializerBehavior(endpoint.Contract);
    serviceHost.Open();
```

**Creating channel:**

```
m_ChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IService>(m_Binding, new EndpointAddress(m_Url));

ObjectGraphDataContractSerializerBehavior.SetDataContractSerializerBehavior(m_ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Contract);

foreach (var behavior in endpointBehaviors)
    m_ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(behavior);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It maybe has to do with the selection of which serializer is used. Remove all other serializers and add yours:

```
public static void SetDataContractSerializerBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription)
{
    foreach (OperationDescription operation in contractDescription.Operations)
    {
         DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior dcsob = operation.Behaviors.Find<DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior>();
         if (dcsob != null)
         {
            operation.Behaviors.Remove(dcsob);
         }
         operation.Behaviors.Add(new     ReferencePreservingDataContractSerializerOperationBehavior(operation));
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't believe it was working because I never got to my breakpoint in CreateSerializer. But it works.